# Fetching data from Sql Server 2008 to windows forms using Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have written the following Stored Procedure to fetch data from Sql Server Database based on username provided and display it on a Form.

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Proc_FetchClients]
@FirstName nvarchar(100)
As
--Declare @ReturnVal varchar(100)
SELECT FirstName,LastName,Email,Username,DateOfBirth,Address,PhoneNo,ClientType from Clients
where FirstName=@FirstName
RETURN
```

**C# Code**

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false);
        //Mainform = new Form1(Login);
        string FetchClient = "EXEC Proc_FetchClients'" + TxtUsernameUpdate + "'";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(FetchClient, con);
        adp.Fill(dt);

        TxtNameUpdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
        TxtClientTypeUpdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ClientType"].ToString();
        TxtLnameUpdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();
        TxtEmailUpdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
        TxtUsernameUpdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Username"].ToString();
        TxtDobUpdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["DateOfBirth"].ToString();
        TxtAddressUpdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
        TxtPhoneUpdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["PhoneNo"].ToString();


    }
```

The above code is giving me an error saying row 0 does not exist.I found similar articles here on stackoverflow but didn't get a satisfactory solution.Can anyone tell me the right technique of fetching the data from the database to the form and how to get the data to a data table and then fetch it into Textbox controls?

Comment: which line is giving you error?

Comment: @Taumantis  TxtNameUpdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();

This line

Comment: after apd.Fill dt variable is empty? Or it has some record? dt.Rows.Count() / dt.count is showing something?

Comment: It looks like your SP is simply returning no data, I sugest you profile the database and see what SQL is running. I am actually surprised it runs without error as it looks like it would execute the sql `EXEC Proc_FetchClients'fred'` which has no space between the SP name and the text for firstname. Also You should use parameters rather than string concatenation.

Comment: @BenRobinson I executed the stored procedure EXEC Proc_FetchClients
'Vivek' and it worked fine on Sql Server

Comment: @BenRobinson Thanks a lot bro I changed the statement to 

 string FetchClient = "EXEC Proc_FetchClients'" + TxtUsernameUpdate.Text + "'";

and it worked

Comment: Read about sql injection and parameterized queries.